# text wont activate js and css animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not the best with javascript and I've been asked to include it in a page I'm creating. I'm nearly there, getting a box containing a video, to slide over the screen from above and create a dark overlay. I can only get it to work using an image. I want to activate it from a href text link. I've looked everywhere, but everything I see uses the same method, using an image. Can someone help please?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#activator').click(function() {
    $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast', function() {
      $('#box').animate({
        'top': '120px'
      }, 500);
    });
  });
  $('#boxclose').click(function() {
    $('#box').animate({
      'top': '-500px'
    }, 500, function() {
      $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
a.activator {
  background: url(Overlay/clickme.png) no-repeat top left;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: hand;
}

.overlay {
  background: transparent url(Overlay/images/overlay.png) repeat top left;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.box {
  position: fixed;
  top: -500px;
  left: 20%;
  width: 610px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #7F7F7F;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #F79510;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #333;
  z-index: 101;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="activator"><img src="images/Film-2.png" class="film"></a>
<!-- I want to add the text here, separate to the image, but to do the same activation. -->
```

Comment: Could you please fix the broken image in the stack snippet

Comment: the image is irrelevant, so not sure why you need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you need to add the text inside the original "activator", or create another one.

Try this:

```
<a id="activator"><img src="images/Film-2.png" class="film"></a>
<div id="activator2"> Some text that activates the overlay </div>
```

And in your JS change

```
$('#activator').click(...
```

To:

```
$('#activator, #activator2').click(...
```

Now, both activators will trigger your script that makes the overlay show.

Also, in your CSS, you have `a.activator` while in your HTML is `id="activator"`, but that might be just a typo.

Comment: In that case there may be a lot of typos. Everything in JS is an id and in CSS a class. It could of course be that both exist, but it's impossible to judge due to a lack of HTML.

Comment: Perfect! I did actually try a similar example to the one you've given, but in my haste, I added quotes around each activator, rather than including both inside the quotes.

Comment: @ChrisJones Glad to help you. Please don't forget to mark the question as answered.